# Manage single variable for two different types of data

Tags: swift, generics

I have two UI of listing, the cells are the same in both listing. For both UI, the different `Codable` array is managed. i.e.
`FirstViewController` contains **FirstDataModel** & `SecondViewController` contains **SecondDataModel**.

So in `FirstViewController`, in `cellForRow` method I have called the code :

```
func setPastCell(cell:WeekCell, data_dic:FirstDataModel) {
    cell.lblGoalA.text = predictScore1
    cell.lblGoalB.text = predictScore2
}
```

**Arrays:**

```
struct FirstDataModel: Codable {
    var team1_name:String?
    var team2_name:String?
    var status:Int?
    var image:String?
    var score:Int?

}
struct SecondDataModel: Codable {
    var team1_name:String?
    var team2_name:String?
    var status:Int?
    var image:String?
    var count:Int?
    var balance:Int?
}
```

I want to make common function for both **FirstDataModel** & **SecondDataModel**. So how can I manage it using generic function?

How can I pass `FirstDataModel` or `SecondDataModel` in `setPastCell(cell: WeekCell, data_dic: FirstDataModel)` ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FirstDataModel and SecondDataModel have same properties?

Comment: No they have different properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Craete a protocol with common properties

```
protocol DataModel {
    var team1_name:String? { get }
    var team2_name:String? { get }
    var status:Int? { get }
    var image:String? { get }

}
```

Confirm to the protocol in your structs and add its properties

```
struct FirstDataModel: DataModel, Codable {
    //Protocol properties
    var team1_name:String?
    var team2_name:String?
    var status:Int?
    var image:String?
    //additional properties
    var score:Int?
}
struct SecondDataModel: DataModel, Codable {
    //Protocol properties
    var team1_name:String?
    var team2_name:String?
    var status:Int?
    var image:String?
    //additional properties
    var count:Int?
    var balance:Int?
}
```

As both structs confirm to the DataModel protocol, you can use it in the function parameter.

```
func setPastCell<T: DataModel>(cell:WeekCell, data_dic:T) {

    if let firstModel = data_dic as? FirstDataModel {
        print(firstModel.team1_name)
        print(firstModel.team2_name)
        print(firstModel.status)
        print(firstModel.image)
        print(firstModel.score)
    } else if let secondModel = data_dic as? SecondDataModel {
        print(secondModel.team1_name)
        print(secondModel.team2_name)
        print(secondModel.status)
        print(secondModel.image)
        print(secondModel.count)
        print(secondModel.balance)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to use this in generic type??

Comment: @Dimple You can use func setPastCell<T: DataModel>(data_dic:T) { }

Answer (score 2):

You can inherit the two DataModel from a Protocol, and use Protocol properties in setup.

Example:

```
protocol ModelProtocol {
    var descriptionOne: String { get }
    var descriptionTwo: String { get }
}

struct FirstDataModel: ModelProtocol {}

func setPastCell(cell:WeekCell, data_dic: ModelProtocol) {
    cell.lblGoalA.text = descriptionOne
    cell.lblGoalB.text = descriptionTwo
}
```

Comment: In `ModelProtocol`, It is compulsory to have the same properties in both models? As my both models properties are different